# Divide the population Fortran - receiving zeros

Tags: fortran

I have a program to read and stratify an R file of multivariate normal population with (x, y) values. I want to divide the population into two groups, where the division is based on if x and y is higher or below a specific number.

When I do the stratification in Fortran, I get no results but zeros for x and y, something like this

```
total number of individuals        1551
   0.00000000       0.00000000          
   0.00000000       0.00000000          
   0.00000000       0.00000000         
   0.00000000       0.00000000           
   0.00000000       0.00000000          
   0.00000000       0.00000000         
   0.00000000       0.00000000          
   0.00000000       0.00000000          
   0.00000000       0.00000000          
   0.00000000       0.00000000          

.
.
.
```

The original data looks like this

```
755,885
656,841
742,844
747,829
776,861
696,809
782,891
771,867
760,826
812,830
711,792
736,840
738,873
793,833
751,836
747,871
796,830
711,868
747,843
758,835
760,824
759,839
696,868
```

[I have attached the file to the original data from R as well](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l843kpc3yjpt9ek/xyBVNData_R.txt?dl=0)

```
program test 


implicit none

    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: x,y
    real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: s1, s2, s3, s4
    integer::  io, l1, l2, l3,l4,n,i

    open(33, file = '', status = 'old', action = 'read')
    n = 0 
    DO
        READ(33,*,iostat=io)
        IF (io/=0) EXIT
        n = n + 1
    END DO 

    allocate(x(n) ,y(n)) 
    rewind(33)

    DO i =1,n
        READ(33,*) x(i), y(i)
    END DO

    allocate(s1(n,2))
    allocate(s2(n,2))
    allocate(s3(n,2))
    allocate(s4(n,2))

    s1=0
    s2=0
    s3=0
    s4=0

    l1=1
    l2=1
    l3=1
    l4=1

    do i = 1 , n 
        if (x(i) >=0 .AND. x(i)<=500) then
            if( y(i) >= 0 .AND. y(i) <=500) then
                s1(l1, :)=(/x(i), y(i) /)
                l1=l1+1
            end if 

        else if (x(i)  > 500  .AND.  x(i)  <= 1000 ) then
            if ( y(i) > 0  .AND. y(i) < 500 ) then
                s2(l2, :)=(/x(i), y(i) /)
                l2=l2+1
            end if
        end if

        write(*,*)  s1(l1, :)
    end do !iloop

end program test
```

I have no idea what I am doing here wrong.

Comment: It is the comma in the data - change it to a space

Comment: Welcome. Be sure to go threough the [Tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a tag for a specific version if your question is version specific. But your question is not version specific.

Comment: Your program is very hard to read. Please use consistent line indentation when your code is supposed to be viewed by others. It will help you the see the structure better as well.

Comment: @cup A comma is a legal Fortran delimiter for list directed I/O.

Comment: `file = ''` in the `open` statement?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I still have the problem after changing the comma to a space..@VladimirF I have simplify the code.

Comment: You simplified the code TOO MUCH. We don't see how you read the data. The code should be minimal, but also *complete* and *verifiable*. See [mcve].

Comment: @Due please sort out the indentation of your example. Prior to you updating the question, the formatting had been corrected, but once again your indentation is all over the place. This makes it much harder to follow your logic, and people are less likely to help!

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the "dangling ELSE problem". FORTRAN thinks that the "else if (x(i) > 500 ..." part belongs to the "if( y(i) >= 0 .AND. y(i) <=500)" statement. Add an "END IF" before the "else".

```
 do i = 1 , n 
    if (x(i) >=0 .AND. x(i)<=500) THEN
        if( y(i) >= 0 .AND. y(i) <=500) THEN 
            s1(l1, :)=(/x(i), y(i) /)
                l1=l1+1
        end if
    else if (x(i)  > 500  .AND.  x(i)  <= 1000 )THEN
        if ( y(i) > 0  .AND. y(i) < 500 ) THEN  
            s2(l2, :)=(/x(i), y(i) /)
                l2=l2+1
        END IF 
    END IF 
END do !iloop
```

Comment: @francescalus , sorry what do you really mean? The question already has the values of x and y as well as a link to the actual data file in text format.

Comment: @Rainer Thank you very much. I have tried your idea but I am still facing the same problem. An output with zeros and no values.

Comment: @francescalus You are absolutely right. Thank you so much for pointing that out. It seems I forgot to add it while I was editing the code to post it here. Now the code is edited with initialization of the {x} and {y.}

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: @s8129 Thank you very much. Your code works great and it does exctely what I want. Thank you for your effort and time. I know R which I assume  but with my data, using R is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example data file you have provided, I think the output you are getting is correct. Each case falls into the x > 500, y > 500, and your code does not accommodate writing these entries to a stratification.

Below is, as far as I can understand, a solution to your original question. I have broken the code down into a number of subroutines, which helps make it easier to understand. Note that the assumption in my code is that all data is in the range 0 -- 1000.

```
module util
    implicit none
    private

    public :: get_strat
    public :: write_strat

    contains
        function get_strat(x, y) result(strat)
            integer, intent(in) :: x
            integer, intent(in) :: y
            integer :: strat

            integer, parameter :: mid_val = 500

            if (x < mid_val .and. y < mid_val) then
                strat = 1
            else if (x < mid_val .and. y >= mid_val) then
                strat = 2
            else if (x > mid_val .and. y < mid_val) then
                strat = 3
            else 
                strat = 4
            end if

        end function

        subroutine write_strat(trg, strat, x, y)
            integer, intent(in) :: trg
            integer, intent(in) :: strat(:)
            integer, intent(in) :: x(:)
            integer, intent(in) :: y(:)

            integer :: i, count_strat

            count_strat = 0

            write(*, *) "Writing stratification ", trg
            do i = 1, size(x)
                if (strat(i) == trg) then
                    write(*, *) x(i), y(i)
                    count_strat = count_strat + 1
                end if
            end do
            write(*, *) "Total = ", count_strat
            write(*, *)
        end subroutine 
end module util

program test 
    use util
    implicit none

    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: x,y, strat
    integer::  io, n, i

    open(33, file = 'xyBVNData_R.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
    n = 0 

    do 
        read(33, *, iostat=io)
        if( io /= 0) exit 
        n = n + 1
    end do

    allocate(x(n) ,y(n), strat(n)) 
    rewind(33)

    do i = 1, n
        read(33, *) x(i), y(i)
    end do

    do i = 1, n
        strat(i) = get_strat(x(i), y(i))
    end do

    do i = 1, 4
        call write_strat(i, strat, x, y)
    end do

end program test
```

By breaking down the code like this, it becomes far easier to understand and spot any logical flaws. For example, in your code, the line counting variables `l1`... increment following finding a match. This means that at the end of the program, the count is one greater than the number of matching entries. At clearer idiom would be:

```
l# = 0
...
if (...logic...)
    l# = l# + 1
    !! Do something
end if
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. I have not tried the code yet as I am very bigginer to fortran and I need to understand your code first before I apply it to my data.  However, you deserve a huge thank you anyway for helping others with your knowledge.

Comment: @Due No problem. If you are a beginner to using Fortran, it might be worthwhile to consider whether it is the right language to do this job. (assuming my solution above works) it is definitely possible, but you could probably achieve the same thing with only a couple of lines of Python or Perl. I expect it will also be easier to understand what is going on with these languages.